# How do I update the BIOS of a Samsung Series 9?

Tags: samsung, bios

I'm using a Samsung Series 9 900x3c and since there is a Bios update available for this model (unfortunately only with Windows).

I was wondering if anybody knows a good method to upgrade the Bios without switching back to Windows. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: See [The answers here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/144526/how-to-flash-a-bios-when-only-a-windows-binary-is-provided/144537#144537)

Answer (score 2):

If the Bios updater has a version for Windows XP, you can use [Hiren's Boot CD](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd) to boot a live XP and do the Bios update from there.

Comment: Unfortunately not, only a Windows 7 Version is provided and while for most other applications I would not care so much for that, I don't want to risk it with a Bios update.