# Installing updated BIOS for Dell 530s, keep getting "insufficient memory" error?

Tags: dell, ram, bios

I have tried using both virtual and real FreeDOS disks to load the file, but I can't get it to work- I run only Ubuntu 12.04 and I'm looking to upgrade my CPU, but every time I try to run the 530_1018.exe file on my FreeDOS flash disk, it expands it, says "insufficient memory" once it gets to the Award Bios Flasher, and deletes the expanded file. Any suggestions would be very helpful- thank you!

P.S.-I am planning on adding 2 additional Gb of RAM, so if that will solve the problem, I don't mind waiting until that comes.

EDIT: I opened it up, looks like a Foxconn G33M02 motherboard.

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/144526/how-to-flash-a-bios-when-only-a-windows-binary-is-provided/144537#144537), It might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this when you have installed the 2 GB RAM.  If the problem persists at that point, please revisit this post with an update.