# Installing Ubuntu in a Virtual Machine

Tags: software-center

I was trying to install Ubuntu on a Virtual Machine, i was downloaded the 64Bits version and it was all good until this appears "this kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detects an i686 CPU. Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU."
what i do now?

Information:
  CPU: Intel Core i7 IvyBridge 3.40Ghz
  RAM: 6Gb
  OS: Windows 7 64Bits

Comment: Please add which virtualization software you are running.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a virtual machine configuration issue.

While your host OS might be 64 bits you will also have to make sure that your virtual machine is configured to be 64 bits as well.

Virtualization of a 64-bit OS requires certain hardware features. Not all 64-bit CPUs have these features, or have them enabled. See my other answer :

[Can't install a 64-bit virtualbox on 64-bit 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160176/cant-install-a-64-bit-virtualbox-on-64-bit-12-04/207801#207801)

The 32-bit version may be suitable, as long as you don't need 64-bit features (like a large amount of RAM per process).

Answer (score 0):

When you chose the Operating System -sometimes you can choose between Ubuntu and Ubuntu 64 bits- and the CPU you could have probably chosen a 32 bit edition.