# Virtual box 4.3 error not support 64 bit?

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, windows-8

I'm using oracle **virtual box 4.3.10** (64bit) and **ubuntu 12.04** 64bit  ut in the VM it **only** shows 32 bit versions.how can i fix this? I have tried some options but failed. Please help me out

[image]

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I run a 64-bit guest in VirtualBox?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/41550/how-do-i-run-a-64-bit-guest-in-virtualbox)

Comment: also see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/256792/how-do-i-enable-hardware-virtualization-technology-vt-x-for-use-in-virtualbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had this issue before, and It turned out to be from the BIOS.

You should enable VirtualMachine support from the bios setup.

I hope that this what is preventing your 64 from showing up.

Answer (score 1):

I've also had this issue, Enabling virtualization did not solve it.

in order to solve it you have to first upgrade your BIOS to a newer version, preferably its final version. Then enable virtual machine support from your bios setup and recheck the virtualbox or reinstall it if needed.

It worked perfect for me.

It seems there is an incompatibility between Virtualbox 4.3 and older BIOS versions.

Hope it helps...